# Getting a 500 Internal Server Error when trying to register a new user using MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, authentication, next.js

> **I am building a web application using next js, *MongoDB, sanity*, and I am currently working on the user registration functionality. However, when I try to submit the registration form, I get a 500 Internal Server Error and the registration process fails.**

### Here is the relevant code:

#### Server-side code:

```
// Register a new user
import connectMongo from '../../../database/conn';
import Users from '../../../model/Schema';
import { hash } from 'bcryptjs';

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  try {
    await connectMongo();
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Failed to connect to MongoDB' });
  }

  if (req.method !== 'POST') {
    return res.status(405).json({ error: 'HTTP method not allowed. Only POST requests are accepted.' });
  }

  if (!req.body) {
    return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Request body is missing.' });
  }

  const { username, email, password } = req.body;

  const existingUser = await Users.findOne({ email });
  if (existingUser) {
    return res.status(422).json({ error: 'User already exists.' });
  }

  try {
    const hashedPassword = await hash(password, 12);
    const newUser = await Users.create({ username, email, password: hashedPassword });
    return res.status(201).json({ success: true, user: newUser });
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Failed to create user.' });
  }
}
```

#### Client-side code:

```
// Handle submission of registration form
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const options = {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    body: JSON.stringify(values)
  }

  try {
    const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/auth/signup', options)
    const data = await res.json();
    if (data.ok) router.push('http://localhost:3000')
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}
```

> **I have checked the server-side logs and I am not seeing any specific error messages or stack traces that indicate where the issue might be occurring. I have also tried running the server-side code in a debugger, but I am still unable to pinpoint the issue.**
>
> **Could someone please help me troubleshoot this issue and figure out what might be causing the 500 Internal Server Error? I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions. Thank you in advance!**

Answer (score 0):

> I get a 500 Internal Server Error and the registration process fails.

If you're getting an `Internal Server Error` without any extra information, that suggests that the 500 is coming from uncaught-error handling code somewhere else in your server. I'd search for `res.status(500)` to see if there's code that's transforming uncaught errors into 500s. If you add logging to that code, you should hopefully see the error that's causing the 500.

In koa, that error code middleware will look something like this (placed at the beginning of the middleware):

```js
app.use(async (ctx, next) => {
  try {
    await next();
  } catch (err) {
    if (!err.status && !err.statusCode) {
      console.error("Uncaught Error -- turning into 500", err, err.message);
      err.status = 500;
    }
    throw err;
  }
});
```

In the code you shared, the one potential spot for a thrown error I see if `await Users.findOne({ email })`. Throwing when unable to find a document is a somewhat common pattern, but I don't know how things are set up in your codebase.

> I have also tried running the server-side code in a debugger, but I am still unable to pinpoint the issue.

When you're running the code in a debugger, make sure to set up a breakpoint at the start of the route so that you can step through the code line by line. You can type `debugger;` at the start of your route to set a breakpoint (but your editor might have a nicer way of setting this up!)